# How to add navigation to this js slider

Tags: javascript

VERY new to JS and I need to add navigation to this image slider that my website uses. Like arrows that let me move back and forth between the images. I know it's got something to do with this part of the code

```
#slider div.navBulletsWrapper  {
        display:none;
        top:320px;/* Its position is relative to the #slider */
        text-align:center;
        background:none;
        position:relative;
        z-index:5;
```

But I don't know what command the "display:" is supposed to have. Here is the full js code below.

```
    /* http://www.menucool.com */

#sliderFrame, #sliderFrame div {
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
#sliderFrame 
{
    position:relative;
    width:660px;
    margin:0 auto; /*center-aligned*/
}

#slider, #slider div.sliderInner {
    width:660px;height:280px;/* Must be the same size as the slider images */
}

#slider {
    background:#fff url(loading.gif) no-repeat 50% 50%;
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto; /*center-aligned*/
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px #999999;
}

/* image wrapper */
#slider a.imgLink, #slider div.video {
    z-index:2;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;left:0px;border:0;padding:0;margin:0;
    width:100%;height:100%;
}
#slider .video {
    background:transparent url(video.png) no-repeat 50% 50%;
}

/* Caption styles */
#slider div.mc-caption-bg, #slider div.mc-caption-bg2 {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    padding:10px 0;/* 10px will increase the height.*/
    left:0px; /*if the caption needs to be aligned from right, specify by right instead of left. i.e. right:20px;*/
    bottom:0px;/*if the caption needs to be aligned from top, specify by top instead of bottom. i.e. top:150px;*/
    z-index:3;
    overflow:hidden;
    font-size: 0;
}
#slider div.mc-caption-bg 
{
    /* NOTE: Its opacity is to be set through the sliderOptions.captionOpacity setting in the js-image-slider.js file.*/
    background:Black;/* or any other colors such as White, or: background:none; */
}
#slider div.mc-caption-bg2 {
    background:none;
}
#slider div.mc-caption {
    font: bold 14px/20px Arial;
    color:#EEE;
    z-index:4;
    text-align:center;
    background:none;
}
#slider div.mc-caption a {
    color:#FB0;
}
#slider div.mc-caption a:hover {
    color:#DA0;
}


/* ------ built-in navigation bullets wrapper ------*/
/* Note: check themes\2\js-image-slider.css to see how to hide nav bullets */
#slider div.navBulletsWrapper  {
    display:none;
    top:320px;/* Its position is relative to the #slider */
    text-align:center;
    background:none;
    position:relative;
    z-index:5;
}

/* each bullet */
#slider div.navBulletsWrapper div 
{
    width:8px; height:8px;
    font-size:0;color:White;/*hide the index number in the bullet element*/
    background:transparent url(bullet.png) no-repeat 0 0;
    display:inline-block; *display:inline; zoom:1;
    overflow:hidden;cursor:pointer;
    margin:0 6px;/* set distance between each bullet*/
}

#slider div.navBulletsWrapper div.active {background-position:0 -11px;}


/* --------- Others ------- */

#slider div.loading 
{
    width:100%; height:100%;
    background:transparent url(loading.gif) no-repeat 50% 50%;
    filter: alpha(opacity=60);
    opacity:0.6;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0; 
    z-index:9;
}

#slider img, #slider>b, #slider a>b {
    position:absolute; border:none; display:none;
}

#slider div.sliderInner {
    overflow:hidden; 
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0.000001deg);/* fixed the Chrome not crop border-radius bug*/
    position:absolute; top:0; left:0;
}

#slider>a, #slider video, #slider audio {display:none;}
#slider div {-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);transform: translate3d(0,0,0);}
```

Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: Where is js ???

Comment: This isn't JavaScript, this is all CSS. To do what you're suggesting you would probably want to wrap portions of your slider in an `a` tag but you can't do that in CSS and we don't have enough information here to give you an answer. We need a small, minimal example with some markup, your javascript functionality, and your css. The code you've provided doesn't get us anywhere when it comes to helping you, sorry to say.

Comment: Did you try other values for the display property? You say you think it's that, but have you tried it at all?